# How to change password of `admin` account in `flowable-design` for publishing app?

Tags: flowable

I've installed `Flowable 3.6.1` in my localhost. But when I changed the `Host` configuration in `Tomcat` folder, I found `flowable-design` was unable to publish app to `flowable-engage`.

After tens of times attempts, I found the configuration located at `Tomcat/webapps/flowable-engage/WEB-INF/classes/flowable-default.properties` as following:

```
flowable.common.app.idm-url=http://localhost:8080/flowable-work
flowable.common.app.idm-admin.user=admin
flowable.common.app.idm-admin.password=test
```

So, I changed `admin`'s password here, but it was not working actually. However, I guess the file name was the problem. Then I changed the file name to `flowable.properties`, it was still not working.

---

**REMEMBER**: In `Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/index.html`, `flowable` told that username and password in different `flowable` application is independent. If you want to change `admin`'s password, you had to know which application you are going to apply these changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a long time digging, I finally found the solution to put these three configuration in `Tomcat/bin/setenv.bat` as following:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dflowable.common.app.idm-url=http://<domain>/flowable-engage/ -Dflowable.modeler.app.deployment-api-url=http://<domain>/flowable-engage/app-api -Dflowable.modeler.app.undeployment-api-url=http://<domain>/flowable-engage/platform-api/app-deployments -Dflowable.common.app.idm-admin.user=admin -Dflowable.common.app.idm-admin.password=<password>"
```

And these properties are loaded in `flowable-ui-design-conf` module, look 
 at 
 `com.flowable.design.conf.ApplicationConfiguration#basicHttpClientProvider(FlowableCommonAppProperties commonAppProperties)` for more information.

Cause I want my `flowable-design` to be able to deploy `app` to `flowable-engage`, so I changed `admin`'s password in `flowable-engage`.